# Match function returning error - vba-excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use a form and when the first box is completed textbox2 will be automatically completed by an Index Match Function.
The Index information is in a table in the first sheet.
When running the code I get an error "Sub or Function not defined".

I have already used a Vlookup without success

```
Me.TextBox2.Text = Index(Worksheets(1).Range("Tabela1[Vessel name]"), Match(Me.TextBox1, Worksheets(1).Range("Tabela1[IMO]"), 0))
```

The code should read TextBox1 (will be entered by user and correspond to IMO), and TextBox2 should be filled with the "Vessel Name"

Comment: Index is not a build in function, did you define Index somewhere yourself? And I think you have one too many )'s at the end.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `WorksheetFunction.Index`?

Comment: @erazorv4 Thank you for your suggestion. I have searched before posting and couldn't find anyone defining the Index function. Can you give me a tip on how to do that?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you use `WorksheetFunction.Index` like FunThomas suggested?

Comment: No. I have changed it as follows and now I have a "Run time error '1004' Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class"

`Me.TextBox2.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("ISM Database").Range("Tabela1[Vessel name]"), Application.WorksheetFunction.match("TextBox1", Sheets("ISM Database").Range("Tabela1[IMO]"), 0))`

Comment: I have typed the desired code directly in excel and it worked just fine: `=INDEX(Tabela1[[#Todos];[Vessel name]];MATCH(A27;Tabela1[[#Todos];[IMO]];0))`
In this case, A27 would be TextBox1 input